# override config settings when using a fat jar for spark on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, typesafe-config

I'm writing a spark application, and using sbt assembly to create a fat jar, which I can send to spark-submit (through Amazon EMR).
My application uses typesafe-config, with a `reference.conf` file inside my `resources` directory.
My jar is on Amazon S3, and I use the command `aws emr add-steps..` to create a new spark job (which downloads the jar to the cluster and sends it to spark-submit).
I know that in general, I can use `application.conf` to override the settings. However, since I'm using spark (and a fat jar), I need some way to deploy my override.

What is the recommended way of overriding the application config settings when using spark?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use spark-submit... --conf my.app.config.value=50 --conf config.file=other.conf ... fat.jar

When using typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load(), values specified on the command line will override theses specified in 'other.conf' which in turn override thoses specified in 'reference.conf' in your fatjar.

Answer (score 0):

In my spark java code I write like this to override application config

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
    sparkConf.setMaster(sparkMaster);
    sparkConf.set("spark.executor.memory", "1024M");

    sparkConf.set("spark.default.parallelism", "48");
    sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
```

Comment: Hi Sandesh, I don't need to override spark's configuration. My application also has a configuration file (reference.conf), which is being packaged in a fat jar with all the rest of the resources (when i use sbt assembly).
Sometimes I want to override one of the settings in the configuration.
I can do this if i write this setting in a new file called application.conf, as it is being supported in typesafe config. However, since the application is being activated with `aws emr add-steps..`, it can't see the application.conf.

Comment: i.e if i have this setting in my reference.conf: `"age" = 18`, how can override it to 21 without creating a new fat jar?